# Configure could not find version of library

Tags: boost, compilation, makefile, gnu, configure

I'am trying to compile a program named fuego on my 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 machine. If I try to run configure I get the error in the title described. I tried to compile an older version of fuego with the same result. I tried to install different lib's and to link to them, but it seems I have done this wrong or it was the wrong approach. 
I have basic knowledge about UNIX systems. I added the configure.log (I renamed it) to provide informations. 
If you need any ohter logs please tell me. I'am grateful for any help or suggestions.

[My configure_v1.log on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iiLCUiE2)

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Try running this instead:

```
./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Hi thanks for providing help, but I end up with this error http://pastebin.com/a13z0Ya2

Comment: didn't help also here on a 64bit wheezy. ended up with the same error message

Answer (score 4):

For ARM architecture (Raspberry Pi, etc): add --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf at the end to avoid boost library error